# Does Samsung Galaxy Grand Support USB OTG?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, usb, usb-on-the-go, samsung-galaxy-grand

Hii Everyone iam Using Samsung Galaxy Grand (GT-I9082) Duos Model and it is running with Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean Version. I Just Wanted to know whether my device supports USB-OTG Cable Support For Connecting USB Drives i have Searched for the same in google and found different answers like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeQqKsarlBI)
video from YouTube is saying that my device doesn't support OTG and in other site [here](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130718222933AA6slD0) saying that my device will support OTG

Please Help Me to know whether my device supports OTG or not

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The Galaxy Grand kernel does not support OTG from what I can see. There may be a custom Kernel to support it if you are willing to root etc, the only one I found was for 4.1.2 and abandoned due to huge number of bugs. Try XDA developers for your device and see what custom kernels are available. As it stands you don't have that option (unless something in the firmware has changed in the last few months). http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2359166 Seems to confirm there isn't a kernel you can use for this I'm afraid.

Comment: @RossC Your comment is a better answer than any of the answers on this question! Please post it as an answer so people stop posting bad answers.

Answer (score 2):

The Galaxy Grand kernel does not support OTG from what I can see. There may be a custom Kernel to support it if you are willing to root etc, the only one I found was for 4.1.2 and abandoned due to huge number of bugs.

Rooting will void your manufacturer/carrier warranty and is not for the wary or anyone who can't risk losing all data from their device.

Try XDA developers for your device and see what custom kernels are available. As it stands you don't have that option (unless something in the firmware has changed in the last few months). [This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2359166) seems to confirm there isn't a kernel you can use for this I'm afraid.

[This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2239898) has an experimental kerlel, which may help, but as previously stated there are warranty, and functionality issues with any custom kernel.

[IF you decide to root your device, this link has a how-to guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2294734) which you use at **your own risk!**

Read, and read some more before you decide. Back up everything and follow the steps to the letter. Ensure that you have the EXACT same device as in the thread also.

**DISCLAIMER: ROOTING YOUR PHONE WILL PROBABLY VOID YOUR WARRANTY FROM BOTH THE CARRIER AND THE MANUFACTURER. IF YOU DO NOT WISH TO ACCEPT FAULT FOR ANY ADVERSE EFFECTS OF ROOTING, THEN DO NOT RISK IT. HERE BE DRAGONS.**

Answer (score 1):

Is your device rooted? If not try rooting and installing [USB OTG Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.shajul.usbotg&hl=en) or [Stickmount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount&hl=en). These apps work only on rooted devices and help to mount USB devices.

However, USB OTG Helper app has a [site](http://usbotghelper.wordpress.com/confirmed-devices/) which has a database of supported device.  Even there confusion prevails. A user has commented as:
[image]

The best way to know is to try is to root and try these apps yourself.  By rooting you can change kernels that could help these apps to mount USB drives.

There is a [XDA webpage](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2239898), which seems to show some light at the end of the tunnel. However, patching kernels are not for faint hearted and I would not advice to take that path, if you are hesitating even to root.

Comment: Rooting Voids Device's Warranty how can i do that ??

Comment: Unfortunately that's true in India. Samsung says in its warranty agreement that warranty will be void, if it detects changes made to its software. There could be a chance if in such cases you could flash the original stock ROM before claiming warranty. However, I am not sure whether there are QFuses/bootloader unlocking etc are involved which would inform the service centre that you had attempted to root.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Galaxy Grand (GT-I9082) Duos 4.2.2 Jelly Bean does not support OTG. I checked.

Comment: How did you check and where?

Answer (score 0):

You could check with [USB Host Diagnostics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics) - though, you'd need to get a USB OTG adaptor and actually plug something in to check.

I'd also add, while many devices may support USB OTG, they may not support plugging in mass storage devices - I have a tablet that I can use a keyboard with, but not USB drives.

I do seem to find a lot of references to it not working, like RossC's link, but nothing that says it does.