# USB OTG Hardware support on Galaxy Grand Duos

Tags: usb-on-the-go, samsung-galaxy-grand

Does Galaxy Grand Duos have hardware support for OTG ? Is it just restricted by software or is hardware support also lacking.

I am little bit confused after reading this [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59681/does-samsung-galaxy-grand-support-usb-otg).

Comment: As the +2 voted answer said, the kernel is crucial in supporting OTG, and by default no support is present for such low-end devices.

Comment: What if I flash the kernel ? Then do I get OTG support ? By question is that is the hardware at all present for the OTG ?

Comment: I don't really think hardware is of concern. Back when I was using the age-old Nokia N900, OTG was not even a concept, so the Manufacturer never had provision for it, yet people still crafted kernels for it and used a tool to enable OTG.